# [EDITED]Is Android Support Package have any debelity?

Tags: android

Lately  I was using support package android like `actionbar activity` or `fragment activity` to build an app.  I combined many tutorial that don't use support package to my project, so the project can do thing that I need, but sadly, I had to overcome many errors, and that why this question fly in my head ...

I try to learn how the support package works, the articles pretty much said that support package works the same as the main package(is that we call it? sorry, I don't know), the difference is the support package works for android prior to honeycomb ...

And lastly is that okay to use both support package and main package together like using actionbar activity and fragment....

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unable to understand your question. Where you asking about the naming conventions of programming for Andorid?

Comment: which part that u doesn't understand ? ... i talk about support library android

Comment: i tried to use any tutorial that not run in android prior to honeycomb because it doesn't use support library and recoded it so the project can run in android below honey comb but i got many error

Comment: Ok, what do you mean about 'harming your code'? Thanks.

Comment: That just a metaphor ... sorry if this forum didnt use thing like that .... I will edit the title

Comment: And thanks for down vote it

Comment: Don't be mean. I never downvoted you man.

Comment: i'm sorry  for my bad word

Answer (score 2):

There are some features that were added on later versions of Android such as ActionBar (post-Honeycomb) or RecycleView (post-Lollipop).
Using the support packages, we can use these features even on devices running earlier versions of Android.
They don't harm your code in any way.

Comment: Do that mean its better to use support package . Than doesnt use it?